# Electron - Send push notifications to subscribed users using temporary link

Tags: node.js, push-notification, electron, google-cloud-messaging

I'm experimenting with push notifications. I want to make a simple electron app that will give to the user the ability to create an ngrok link to send to friends where thy can subscribe to the user who generated the link push notifications. I'm reading about GCM and it seems to be a good solution as a server to send notifications. My question is, if I store the device id of each user that will subscribe into a local database of the app, can I send notifications to the subscribed devices using GMC without authenticate the user into my app?

Comment: To be clear, say John uses your Electron app, generates an Ngrok link and sends it to David. David then opens the Ngrok link in the browser and you want David to be subscribed to notifications John sends? Yes this is possible but it's too broad a question for Stackoverflow. My advice would be to have a go at it and if it doesn't work ask a separate question here on Stackoverflow. Word of caution though, notifications might not work if the Ngrok is HTTP only.

Comment: ngrok offer also https tunnel. What I want to achive is to create a subscription system without the user who subscribe need to have the same app installed. I will try to implement it and if I have a problem I will post a new question. Thanks for the clarification about the argument. I was thinking that FCM was working only if the device have the same app installed

Comment: I see, from what I know about using FCM this should definitely be possible. I'd suggest checking that you can send notifications to an HTTP Ngrok just in the browser first. If you want to receive notifications in your Electron app that's a little harder but possible if you follow these examples: [electron-push-receiver](https://github.com/MatthieuLemoine/electron-push-receiver), [electron-fcm-demo](https://github.com/CydeSwype/electron-fcm-demo)